# OperationalError: could not connect to server. Error while launching odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I am getting this error when trying to run odoo 10:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help others facing same issue, I solved this by following these steps
first i killed all the running processes

```
ps ax | grep odoo

sudo kill -9 (process_id)
```

then I checked the postgresql status and restarted the postgresql.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status

sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

And the issue was successfully resolved!

Comment: By any chance, are you using windows WSL? In windows, every time I start WSL, I get the same error and need to start db service with `sudo service postgresql start`.

Comment: I am using ubuntu16.04